# Reading list like values from dataframe cell

Tags: r

I have pulled data from facebook api `fbRads`. Here is the sample of data frame I have:

```
mydata <-  fread('ID,ACTIONS
      02,"list(action_type = c("link_click", "post_reaction", "page_engagement", "post_engagement"), value = c("1", "4", "5", "5"))"
      03,"list(action_type = c("app_custom_event.fb_mobile_activate_app", "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_add_to_cart", "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_content_view", "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_purchase", "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_search", "app_custom_event.other", "like", "link_click", "mobile_app_install", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_cart", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_wishlist", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_lead", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_search", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content", "post_reaction", "page_engagement", "post_engagement", "offsite_conversion", "app_custom_event"), value = c("994", "219", "1696", "9", "47", "425", "67", "2267", "37", "348", "53", "3", "7", "218", "3286", "145", "2479", "2412", "3915", "3390"))"
      04,"NULL"
      05,"list(action_type = c("app_custom_event.fb_mobile_activate_app", "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_add_to_cart", "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_content_view", "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_purchase", "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_search", "app_custom_event.other", "like", "link_click", "mobile_app_install", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_cart", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_wishlist", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_lead", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_search", "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content", "post", "post_reaction", "page_engagement", "post_engagement", "offsite_conversion", "app_custom_event"), value = c("1703", "188", "2233", "13", "155", "731", "229", "2568", "62", "303", "46", "7", "17", "257", "4433", "1", "473", "3271", "3042", "5063", "5023"))"')
```

I need find values for `app_custom_event.fb_mobile_purchase` against each id. ACTION column contains two list in each cell i.e. `action_type` and `value`.
The output which I am expecting is :

```
mydata <-  fread('ID,app_custom_event.fb_mobile_purchase
      02,"NULL"
      03,"9"
      04,"NULL"
      05,"13"')
```

Do I need to use dictionaries to get the values? Any approach will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
lapply(mydata$ACTIONS, function(i){
  x <- eval(parse(text = i))
  ix <- which(x$action_type == "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_purchase")
  x$value[ ix ]
})
```

I don't know about *fbRads* package, but it must have some "read" function, to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I have been through the documentation of this package. There is no such read function which will give me data in table format